# ADO Recordset.Open does not raise error

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

I'm using Delphi 10 to access MSSQL 2012 via ADO. All works fine except one case: when I'm opening AdoQuery that was broken by time out, but `Recordset.Open` method does not raise exception, instead next call to Recordset.RecordCount raise exception `$80004005 (E_FAIL)`.

Probably it is because some data was already fetched (in SSMS it looks so). Is it possible to force Open method raise exception? Or how can I catch this situation without exception?

P.S. Yes, I can catch this exception, but looking for more gracefull method.

Comment: Did you use AsyncExecute flag?

Comment: No, simple synchronous TAdoQuery with default properties

Comment: What is `Recordset`? is it `TAdoQuery` or `TAdoQuery.Recordset`?

Comment: It is TAdoQuery.Recordset

Comment: Any reason why you use `TAdoQuery.Recordset.Open` instead of `TAdoQuery.Open`? In any case try to check the `Recordset.State`

Comment: @kobik: I use only standard TAdoQuery methods (TAdoQuery.Open, TAdoQuery.Close, etc), i have pointed Recordset.Open as a source of the problem (also Recordset.RecordCount is called inside of TAdoQuery.RecordCount)